# Ruby on rails require jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Does Jquery have to be manually included in rails? Or is it a default? I see in the asset pipeline manifest:

```
require jquery
require jquery-ujs
```

Comment: It is a default since the time it replaced prototype..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to be included, but it will be included unless you remove it. Most applications will benefit from it being present, but if you don't use JavaScript in any of your views, you could always leave it out.